# Devo usar HTTPS ou SSH no Gitlab ? Quais seriam as diferenças?

Tags: git, https, ssh, gitlab

Notei que no gitlab há duas maneiras de clonar um projeto, uma pelo SSH e outra pelo HTTPS, minha dúvida é qual seria a diferença entre elas ?

Em questão de segurança qual seria o recomendado usar para efetuar tal procedimento ?

Comment: Não sei porque está marcada como duplicada, a outra pergunta é antiga  e contem informações defasadas, hoje o github marca o HTTPS como recomendado e ele pode ser facilmente utilizado no Bash

Comment: Obrigado Silas, não entendo porque marcaram como duplicada, eu não perguntei sobre vantagens mas sim se devo usar o ssh ou https.

Comment: Já que não dá pra colocar respostas, eu respondo aqui mesmo. Eu recomendo usar HTTPS porque é o padrão que a web usa. até o Google chrome marca sites que  usam https como seguros, como o próprio stackoverflow. outra coisa é que quando você for dar push em repositórios usando Https ele pede sua senha e login do repositorio e o ssh funciona de uma maneira completamente diferente, com chaves e etc. Ou seja, se você usar o SSH, qualquer pessoa com acesso ao seu computador pode dar Push nos seus repositorios. Saiba mais em: https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/